# How to use currently logged in Windows Active Directory user to login to a web app?

Tags: javascript, windows, authentication, web-applications, active-directory

I want to use the current logged in Windows AD account to authenticate with my web app.  It's fine (desired, actually) to have the front end pass the authentication token (or whatever form that takes in AD) to the back end for validation with our SSO provider.  But how do I get the AD information into the front end, so that it *can* be passed the back end?  What does this info look like, how is it acquired, etc?  I can't find any tutorials or guidance on the topic.

I know this is possible because I see it being done on other web apps, but I don't know how to do it myself and am having a very hard time finding a solution.

Comment: How is your web app hosted? Is it in IIS?

Comment: It is likely to be a NodeJS back end.  The front end will likely be hosted as static assets using simple HTTPS protocol.

Comment: Without seeing any code, I would use python with an LDAP library.  Then I would use GET/POST requests to send to user AD info to back end.

Comment: @JasonOwens that part is a cake walk for me, but how do you get the AD info on the front end, so that you can send it to the back end?

Comment: You are looking for Windows Authentication, which is performed by the web server and passed to your application. So it depends on which web server you are using. Which web server will this be hosted in? (IIS, Apache, Express, etc)

Comment: @GabrielLuci this will be a Node (likely Express) server.  I don't understand how the user (client side) can be authenticated by the web server (back end) so that the web server can send that authentication to the application, without the back end first learning something about the user on the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want seamless login (so the user doesn't have to type in their username/password) then you will want Windows Authentication. You can read about how it works [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mist/2018/02/14/windows-authentication-http-request-flow-in-iis/).

To make this work with Node.js Express you can use the [NodeSSPI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sspi) package. The documentation has examples on how to use it.

The browser will also have to trust your site before it will send credentials automatically. For IE and Chrome, that means adding the site to the list of Trusted Sites in the Internet Options. Firefox keeps its own list in the `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris` setting in about:config